# ¿Cómo puedo realizar esta consulta en MYSQL de la mejor forma posible?

Tags: mysql, sql

Me encuentro con un problema que no logro resolver, espero me puedan ayudar. Seguramente sea algo simple pero estoy comenzando a relacionarme más con SQL.
Necesito comparar un dato de una tabla con otro de otra tabla.
En palabras sería lo siguiente:

```
Tengo dos tablas:
Tabla AccountsType: ID|UserID|Password
Tabla AccountsBC: ID|Cash
Las columnas ID de AccountsType y AccountsBC están relacionadas, son FOREIGN_KEYS.
```

Necesito que me traiga el ID de un UserID específico y que una vez que tenga ese ID lo ultilice para traer los datos de la columna Cash con el mismo ID.

Espero me haya explicado lo mejor posible, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Qué consulta usaste y qué resultado te dió? Lee: [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Mientras, también podes leer algo sobre `joins` en MySQL

Comment: Intenté utilizar INNER JOIN para comparar las tablas, pero no logré mi objetivo. No logro formular bien la lógica creo yo, entiendo que debería utilizar INNER JOIN para comparar la igualdad de los ID entre una tabla y otra, ¿estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Si. Editá la pregunta y añadí la consulta que conseguiste formar para que podamos ver qué está pasando. Y no te olvides de usar el formato correcto para presentar las tablas con sus nombres respectivos.

Comment: Ya lo hice y con la solución, al final pude resolverlo!

Comment: Genial. Pone tu solución en la respuesta Y editá la pregunta y  formatea el código para que sea mas legible. Y te doy mi +1.

Comment: Deberías colocar tu solución como respuesta a tu pregunta para poder ayudar a otros usuarios, deberías colocar el nombre de las tablas para que se comprenda mejor, claramente en este caso es fácil entender pero en estructuras mas complejas no seria tan sencillo identificar cuales son las tablas "A, B, C, etc".

Comment: Hola, ya he hecho lo que me han dicho. Soy nuevo en StackOverflow, muchas gracias por sus recomendaciones.

Answer (score 1):

He resuelto el problema con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT Cash 
FROM AccountsType 
WHERE ID= ( 
SELECT ID 
FROM AccountsBC 
WHERE UserID='X');
```